# How to flatten a object containing list to an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb aggregation and added a `facet` stage. Here is the output of this stage.

```
{
    "a": [{x: 1}, {x: 2}],
    "b": [{x: 3}, {x: 4}]
}
```

Now I want to get rid of the `a` and `b` keys and create a list of objects from it. So final result should be like the following:

```
[
    {x: 1}, 
    {x: 2},
    {x: 3}, 
    {x: 4}
]
```

What should I use in to aggregation pipeline for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {_id: 0, data: {$concatArrays: ["$a", "$b"]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rW4aSlWofAG)

If you want an array and not an object, add to it:

```
 {$unwind: "$data"},
 {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data}}
```

See how it works on the [playground example - no object](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aq9HOTCCmii)